# How to build a model with variables whose effects might be delayed?

Tags: regression, predictive-modeling, data-science-model, correlation

As a personal project, I want to see how certain lifestyle choices (such as alcohol consumption, exercise time, hours worked/slept, time I get up and go to sleep) affect my mood. While I know the basics of multiple regression, the projects I've done predict a value for a row based on the variables *in that row* (e.g., if gold goes up one day, then this-or-that currency pair is likely to go one way or the other *on the same day*).

But most of the variables I'm interested in likely have belated or multi-day effects. So how do I account for these effects or -- better still -- approximate how long they last? For example,

1. How long does it take my brain to make up for a night of poor sleep?
2. Is one Thursday night happy hour just as bad as the same number of drinks spread out over a few days?
3. If so, how many days?

**My naive idea** is to have several moving averages as features: e.g., avg. sleep the night before, for the past two nights, for the past three ... But not only does this approach seem ungainly and arbitrary (e.g., how do I decide how many previous days are "enough"?), but it also fails to account for belated effects: for all I know, a lack of sleep is actually beneficial the next day, and only starts hurting three days later!

What suggestions do you have?